# Node.js - Connect to same server, same user, using multiple html files

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

What I'm trying to do is integrate my HTML5 canvas games into a single web interface.

When the button is pressed, the html game fills up `<div id="game">`. But I've only defined my node.js in my javascript file.

Now I can probably define it also in the HTML2 file, but it seems it will create 2 seperate connections.

Is there a way of doing this while having only 1 connection?

Simply put - 2 seperate HTML/javascript files with same exact connection

Thank you

HTML

```
<div id="game">
    <button id="gameFile">MyGame</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var socket = io('http://192.168.0.5:2000');

socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('login', {

    });
});
$('#gameFile').click(function(event){
     document.getElementById("game").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="games/myGame/index.html" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" ></object>';
});
```

HTML2 (games/myGame/index.html)

```
<canvas id="myCanvas">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag :(
</canvas>
<script>
    socket.emit('msg', "2nd HTML connected");
</script>
```

Comment: You problem statement is conflicting. Are you going to have 1 web application with 2 views, or 2 separate web application?

Comment: Sorry. 2 seperate applications viewed at once. It's a separate html view embedded inside a general html.

Comment: Can't you use the `sessionId` to determine and join the same room? like, `socket.on('connection', function (socket) {socket.join(socket.handshake.sessionID);});` ?

Comment: The 2nd separate html goes inside the `<div id="game">` tag

Comment: @DavidR I think that is exactly what I'm looking for. Any chance you could give a small quick sample? I'm kind of an amateur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly You can't just do like this.

You will need to connect the socket in case of any other window. 
However, you can sync them using the concept of **ChatRooms** on the server by simply adding all connection pools from a user in a Room.

***####Edit###***

You can simply join a socket connection to a Chatroom :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});
```

Then Simply broadcast a message to that room members:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event'):
```

You can simply use Room-names to be respective to some user identity.

Ref: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Any chance you can provide a quick sample with your answer so I better visually understand? Thank you

Comment: You can simply join a socket connection to a Chatroom :
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join('some room');
});

Then Simply broadcast a message to that room members:

io.to('some room').emit('some event'):

You can simply use Room-names to be respective to some user identity.

Ref: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#